# My edit on a post was rejected then approved - should I have just commented on it?

Tags: discussion

This is concerning https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/208013.

I made an edit to Luchian Grigore's answer to fix some Java syntax errors.  I personally tested my edits and double checked them to see if they were accurate.

Reviewer kleopatra rejected the edit with this comment:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the
>   existing post.

I then informed Luchian of what I discovered with this comment:

> @Luchian - I attempted to edit this post to correct a couple of Java
>   syntax errors, but I was rejected (go figure). 1. If there's an
>   abstract method in a class, the entire class needs to be marked as
>   abstract. 2. In the for loop, you have "i < superClassArray.size".
>   That should be updated to "i < superClassInstance.length" to be
>   consistent/correct with the rest of that code block.

He commented back "ah yes. thanks for that." and then approved the rejected edit.

Was my approach correct on this post or should I have gone about it a different way?

Also, is there a way to contest a rejected edit or request another review of it?

**Edit**
kiamlaluno made me aware (possibly without even knowing) that my edit changed a method in the OP's post that is NOT correct for the object type the OP posted (the "length" method does not exist for Collections in Java which is what I specified in my edit).

So...for the sake of correctness, should I make another edit or comment the post?  Or, is it up to my discretion here?

Sorry for the strangeness in this situation but ultimately just looking for how I should handle this correctly in the future...

Comment: Well - the outcome was that the OP ultimately accepted and acknowledged your corrections.  Mission accomplished if you ask me :P

Comment: @Lix - if the OP had a similar reputation as myself, they would not have been able to approve my edit.

Comment: Perhaps someone else would have come along to approve it.  Users with >3k can make any edits they want, but still need another user to also approve an edit that a lower rep user has made.

Comment: @Lix - do reviewers' review each other's reviews? [say that 5x's fast ;]  I guess I figured it was a done deal after kleopatra rejected my edit.

Comment: Well look - that's a >10k user - they have access to the mod tools - I assume they can approve edits flying solo... And no - the <10k users do not need to be reviewed when making edits...

Comment: On Stack Overflow edits usually require two approval or rejection votes. The exception is that the post's author can immediately approve or reject, without needing a second vote. That's what happened here. (related: [Suggested Edits in the Community FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see an error on the code reported in an answer, just leave a comment for that answer, reporting what the error is.
If the code is completely wrong that requires to be completely re-written, you could consider adding your own answer.

As for the suggested edits, they should follow the following points:

- fix grammatical or spelling errors
- clarify meaning without changing it
- correct minor mistakes
- add related resources or links
- always respect the original author

The third point is probably the one that causes a different behavior about the suggested edits from different users. Changing the code to call a method instead of another is probably not considered a minor mistake from who rejected the edit.

Comment: Just read the edit again and noticed that the OP specified "Collection<SuperClass> superClassInstance" so I was indeed incorrect by suggesting "superClassInstance.length" which is for a Java array rather than a Collection.  That's probably what the reviewer zeroed in on.  OOPS!!

Comment: Yes, there's a big difference between fixing code and fixing grammar. When in doubt, it's probably best to refrain from making edits to code and leave those suggestions as comments instead.